# Custom exception in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, exception

i try to modify an Exception on Laravel. I make an test mysql query which will result in the ModelNotFoundException. But I dont get it to work in the render function.

When I try to do this:

```
dd($exception instanceof ModelNotFoundException)
```

I allways get false. Is it the wrong way or am I doing something completely wrong. The documentation says that it should work. If I log the exception I can see that it is ModelNotFoundException.

Comment: you should use it on `App\Exceptions\Handler` on `render`

Comment: This is where I use it. https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/errors#render-method

Comment: What version of Laravel ?

Comment: Laravel Framework 5.6.12

Comment: `ModelNotFoundException` is from a namespace. Have you `use`d that correctly? If not, it will be trying to match against a class in the current namespace, which is certainly going to fail.